# Подогнать функцию под кривую методом curve_fit модуля scipy

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, scipy, информатика

Всем привет, пытаюсь решить задачу, но не могу, то ли я делаю что то не так, то ли использую не те инструменты.

Есть набор данных, далее представлены в коде.

Есть формула "P*M+(Q-P)*(x)-(Q/M)*(x**2)", мне необходимо подобрать такие параметры P, Q, M, что бы кривая по формуле максимально соответствовала кривой моих данных. И такие параметры есть: P = 0.000572585, Q = 0.249521952, M = 2407.094319

Если пытаюсь найти эти данные через функцию curve_fit модуля scipy, то получаются не  корректные данные. Вот код того что я пытался сделать:

```
import pandas as pd
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# определяем DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193]})
data['cum_sum'] = data['generate'].cumsum()

# описываем функцию, параметры которой необходимо найти
def bass(x, P, Q, M):
    return (P*M+(Q-P)*(x))-(Q/M)*(x**2)

# находим наши параметры
popt, pcov = curve_fit(bass, data.cum_sum[1:23], data.generate[1:23], maxfev = 5000)
print(f'P - {round(popt[0],5)}, Q - {round(popt[1],5)}, M - {round(popt[2],5)}')
# P - 0.00044, Q - 0.21799, M - 26421.35666
# При этом если беру всю выборку, то получаю отрицательные значения

# переопределим наши переменные
P = popt[0]
Q = popt[1]
M = popt[2]

# определим функцию для определения кумулятивных данных
def progcum(gen):
    a = [gen[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(gen)):
        a.append((bass(a[i-1], P, Q, M))+a[i-1])
    return a

# сделаем новые кумулятивные данные, на основе сгенерированных переменных
data['ProgCumul1'] = progcum(data.generate)

# сделаем кумулятивные данные, с идеальными переменными
P = 0.000572585
Q = 0.249521952
M = 2407.094319
data['ProgCumul2'] = progcum(data.generate)

# выведем все графики
plt.plot(data.year, data.generate, 'b-', label='generate')
plt.plot(data.year, data.ProgCumul1, 'r-', label='PrognoseCumulative PQM curve_fit')
plt.plot(data.year, data.ProgCumul2, 'g--', label='PrognoseCumulativeIdeal PQM Ideal')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('generate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

В итоге получаю такой график
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите как или чем правильно получить параметры P, Q и M? Возможно я не правильно все делаю, необходим другой метод. Запутался в каком направлении дальше идти.

Comment: Что такое `bass2`? Эта переменная не определена в коде, код невозможно запустить без неё.

Comment: 2) `bass(a[i-1])` - у функции `bass` должно быть 4 параметра, где они тут? 3) `def grafik(a = data.ProgCumul):` - не делайте так никогда от слова совсем, передавайте параметры в функцию в явном виде. Кроме того, в вашем датасете нет колонки `ProgCumul`, есть только `ProgCumul1`. Это неуважение к участникам форума - публиковать настолько нерабочий код. :/  Если бы вас именно эти ошибки беспокоили - другой вопрос, но тут предполагается же, что код рабочий, просто считает неправильно. А он нерабочий. Совсем.

Comment: Извините за изначально выложенный кривой код, код скорректировал. добавил комментарии, проверил на работоспособность. Подскажите где и в чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Что-то я не понял - а `sales` вы зачем вычисляете, если его не используете? И хотелось бы видеть всё-таки постановку задачи. Сейчас я не понимаю, что из чего вы вычисляете. Получается, что функция вычисляет из кумулятивного значения исходное значение? В чём тут суть?

Comment: У вас `curve_fit` вызван на массиве значений и массиве их сумм. Чему вы функцию учите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный вопрос был решен следующим образом

```
import sys
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

# определяем DataFrame Мировой
data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193]})

# определяем DataFrame Европа
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [3.86302920121212, 4.82858524525252, 7.29549295555556, 11.1764791351515, 14.2443217667677, 22.4547142028283, 26.9342866553535, 36.4259493147475, 44.5311522856566, 59.296786859596, 71.0967493651913, 83.1641398783648, 105.713193767021, 121.353901497536, 135.383228613187, 153.443496864175, 186.657403230905, 215.032405064032, 248.115255753321, 264.815019959907, 318.931230019458, 322.867876348302, 384.216521406329, 403.217594774174, 460.029812809329, 510.138071007773]})

# определяем DataFrame Северная америка
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [3.26221515151515, 3.33473636363636, 3.39524747474747, 3.13325858585859, 4.71233131313131, 5.93275858585859, 7.15238484848485, 10.8848686868687, 12.0094707070707, 15.2516070707071, 19.5614535353535, 29.3507141414141, 38.0231120606061, 59.9658373737374, 81.8704608585859, 105.571632323232, 133.227399166667, 157.24394260101, 184.865083282828, 202.73345020202, 228.356483611111, 270.596628055556, 299.004805909091, 321.654747474747, 348.257532336614, 396.728298131659]})

# определяем DataFrame Центральная и Южная америка
data3 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [0.00777777777777778, 0.0419739852222222, 0.102925997979798, 0.111372380198889, 0.148471920316465, 0.252114795739394, 0.320991025326263, 0.458866738412121, 0.44309745380303, 0.543414491936364, 0.532301140512121, 0.773789270347576, 1.16145997464749, 1.6704335559914, 2.07792761282224, 3.44912776667099, 4.32435901479341, 7.80414735195275, 10.1969105470833, 18.5816815022246, 31.4603868218231, 45.1770034913969, 56.1317767046775, 65.7589869448652, 78.7649400881846, 85.4184260493074]})

# определяем DataFrame Африка
data5 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [0.0063, 0.0071, 0.0072, 0.0076, 0.0198, 0.1755, 0.41558, 0.443584, 0.535599, 0.768280505050505, 0.780382111111111, 0.852565606060606, 1.01622336363934, 1.31177813131313, 1.58923093939543, 2.28458243433914, 2.38650393937963, 2.51563024049708, 3.59344730255575, 5.06007283421232, 8.91068628262324, 11.1763706727939, 12.4577740957429, 14.770723351763, 18.8577291329819, 21.7898430685021]})

# определяем DataFrame Asia Pacific
data6 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [1.12160131313131, 0.991205066484849, 1.21395004149495, 1.48955016659596, 2.05324900639394, 2.56394697970469, 3.51740941797741, 4.06701324667883, 5.34087585515362, 9.18669339997316, 12.019193605714, 18.5698071338417, 24.6031314143647, 36.0798945954192, 54.8479782750866, 81.4841965496602, 113.551087628561, 147.723580093628, 188.472143425882, 214.272687090449, 243.060053246854, 311.20761354133, 387.097778226688, 461.951758065283, 509.368307094495, 572.636106061397]})

# определяем DataFrame Middle East
data7 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                     'generate': [0.001, 0.001, 0.003, 0.003, 0.038, 0.0395, 0.0467, 0.0443, 0.0426, 0.0614, 0.086, 0.1394, 0.155, 0.2101, 0.2405, 0.2222, 0.2258, 0.2166, 0.228089, 0.217278, 0.381789, 0.678, 0.795329, 1.33765, 1.55208140494423, 1.90417927964862]})

data_list = [data, data1, data2, data3, data5, data6, data7]
data_list_name = ['Мировые данные', 'Европа', 'Северная америка', 'Центральная и Южная Америка', 'Африка', 'Азиатско-Тихоокеанский регион', 'Средний Восток']
excel = [[0.000572651035068692, 0.249510681451613, 2407.35925365984],
         [0.0026905792193026, 0.165677960101907, 968.861904875132],
         [0, 0.271427278553528, 479.232809347993],
         [0, 0.534315123417089, 93.3138680129546],
         [0.000225336523079799, 0.318302678325742, 43.1086940618329],
         [1.10946646467203E-07, 0.334963685655578, 774.102168315223],
         [0.0000217806778904624, 0.344168129347132, 7.31265118833075]]
metod_list = ['Nelder-Mead', 'Powell', 'L-BFGS-B', 'TNC', 'SLSQP', 'trust-constr']
sqrt_list = []
vyvod = []
signal = True
r = 0
ind = 0

for k in data_list:
    data = k
    for n in metod_list:
        data['cum_sum'] = data['generate'].cumsum()
        data['Sales'] = [0]+[data['generate'][i+1]-data['generate'][i] for i in range(data.shape[0]-1)]

        finalYear = 2020  # Финальный год

        def Bass(x, P, Q, M):
            """
            Функция расчета Prognose Sales
            x: величина Prognose Cumulative за прошлый год.
            """
            return (P*M+(Q-P)*(x))-(Q/M)*(x**2)

        # Начальные значения параметров
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Bass, data.generate, data.Sales, bounds=(0, np.inf), method='trf', maxfev = 10000)
        p0 = popt[0]
        q0 = popt[1]
        m0 = popt[2]

        def squareMistake(k: tuple, *sales) -> float:
            """
            Функция для минимизации через scipy.
            Рассчитывает сумму квадратов разностей значений
            Prognose Cumulative и Prognose Sales.
            k: кортеж начальных параметров (P, Q, M);
            sales: кортеж Sales.
            """
            # Начальные значения для первого года
            p0 = 0  # Prognose Sales
            c0 = sales[0]  # Prognose Cumulative
            res = 0  # Значение функции
            # Набираем результат функции за годы
            for i in range(1, len(sales)):
                p = Bass(c0, P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2])  # Новый Prognose Sales
                c = c0 + p  # Новый Prognose Cumulative
                res += (c - sales[i])**2  # Добавляем
                # Обновляем значения
                p0 = p
                c0 = c
            return res


        # Формируем данные по годам
        years1 = tuple(data.year)
        gens = tuple(data.generate)

        # Готовим данные для минимизации
        k0 = [p0, q0, m0]  # Начальные значения параметров
        kb = ((0, None), (0, None), (0, None))  # Все параметры неотрицательные

        # Минимизируем сумму квадратов
        try:
            res = minimize(squareMistake, k0, args=gens, method=n, bounds=kb)
        except:
            continue

        k = tuple(res.x)  # Получаем кортеж параметров (P, Q, M)

        # Готовим данные для расчета прогнозов
        years2 = [years1[0]]  # Задаем начальный год
        prSales = [0]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Sales
        prCumul = [gens[0]]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Cumulative

        # Рассчитываем для всех лет
        while years2[-1] < finalYear:
            years2.append(years2[-1]+1)  # Год
            prSales.append(Bass(prCumul[-1], P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2]))  # Prognose Sales
            prCumul.append(prCumul[-1]+prSales[-1])  # Prognose Cumulative

        # Выводим графики для контроля
        pyplot.plot(years2, prCumul, label=f'Sales Bass, метод {n} - {res.success}')  # Расчитанный

        # метрика суммы квадратов остатков (Residual Sum of Squares, RSS). Чем меньше значение RSS, тем лучше кривая описывает данные
        def rss(y_real, y_predicted):
            """Метрика суммы квадратов остатков, Результат должен быть наименьшим.
            """
            squared_residuals = np.square(np.subtract(y_real, y_predicted))
            return sum(squared_residuals)

        data['prCumul'] = prCumul[:len(gens)]
        y_real = data['generate']
        y_predicted = data['prCumul']
        sqrt_list.append(f'{n} {res.success} - {rss(y_real, y_predicted)}')

        # Заносим данные в список для дальнейшего вывода
        if signal:
            if len(vyvod) > 0:
                ind += 1
                nam = data_list_name[ind]
            else:
                nam = data_list_name[ind]
            vyvod.append([nam])
            if r > 0:
                r += 1
            vyvod[r].append('Вручную')
            vyvod[r].append('---')
            vyvod[r].append(excel[ind][0])
            vyvod[r].append(excel[ind][1])
            vyvod[r].append(excel[ind][2])
            # считаем разницу квадратов
            prSalesr = [0]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Sales
            prCumulr = [gens[0]]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Cumulative
            while len(prCumulr) < len(gens):
                prSalesr.append(Bass(prCumulr[-1], P=excel[ind][0], Q=excel[ind][1], M=excel[ind][2]))  # Prognose Sales
                prCumulr.append(prCumulr[-1]+prSalesr[-1])  # Prognose Cumulative
            vyvod[r].append(rss(y_real, prCumulr))

            vyvod.append([nam])
            r += 1
            vyvod[r].append('curve_fit')
            vyvod[r].append('---')
            vyvod[r].append(p0)
            vyvod[r].append(q0)
            vyvod[r].append(m0)
            # c = [Bass(i, p0, q0, m0) for i in y_real]
            # считаем разницу квадратов
            prSalesr = [0]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Sales
            prCumulr = [gens[0]]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Cumulative
            while len(prCumulr) < len(gens):
                prSalesr.append(Bass(prCumulr[-1], P=p0, Q=q0, M=m0)) # Prognose Sales
                prCumulr.append(prCumulr[-1]+prSalesr[-1]) # Prognose Cumulative
            vyvod[r].append(rss(y_real, prCumulr))

            vyvod.append([nam])
            r += 1
            vyvod[r].append(f'{n}')
            vyvod[r].append(f'{res.success}')
            vyvod[r].append(k[0])
            vyvod[r].append(k[1])
            vyvod[r].append(k[2])
            vyvod[r].append(rss(y_real, y_predicted))
        else:
            vyvod.append([nam])
            r += 1
            vyvod[r].append(f'{n}')
            vyvod[r].append(f'{res.success}')
            vyvod[r].append(k[0])
            vyvod[r].append(k[1])
            vyvod[r].append(k[2])
            # считаем разницу квадратов
            prSalesr = [0]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Sales
            prCumulr = [gens[0]]  # Задаем начальный Prognose Cumulative
            while len(prCumulr) < len(gens):
                prSalesr.append(Bass(prCumulr[-1], P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2])) # Prognose Sales
                prCumulr.append(prCumulr[-1]+prSalesr[-1]) # Prognose Cumulative
            vyvod[r].append(rss(y_real, prCumulr))

        signal = False
    signal = True

    pyplot.title(f'{nam}')
    pyplot.plot(years1, gens, label='Sales fact')  # Исходный
    pyplot.xlabel('year')  # Заголовок оси Х
    pyplot.ylabel('generate')  # Заголовок оси Y
    pyplot.legend()  # Отображаем имена данных
    pyplot.show()  # Отображаем график
    # print(input(""))
    # break

columns = ['Генерация', 'Метод', 'Минимизирована', 'P', 'Q', 'M', 'RSS']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=vyvod, columns=columns)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.10f}'.format
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы что-то не то или не так считаете. Давайте просто посчитаем вашу функцию `bass` с одними значениями параметров и с другими. А потом её нарисуем:

```py
P = popt[0]
Q = popt[1]
M = popt[2]

# посчитаем собственно bass с вычисленными P, Q, M
data['bass1'] = data['cum_sum'].apply(lambda x: bass(x, P, Q, M))
...
P = 0.000572585
Q = 0.249521952
M = 2407.094319

# посчитаем bass с "идеальными" P, Q, M
data['bass2'] = data['cum_sum'].apply(lambda x: bass(x, P, Q, M))
...
# добавим их в график
plt.plot(data.year, data.bass1, 'c+', label='bass на P, Q, M вычисленных через curve_fit')
plt.plot(data.year, data.bass2, 'y-', label='bass на "идеальных" P, Q, M')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хм, но судя по графику ваши "идеальные" совсем не идеальны. А вот `curve_fit` сработал очень хорошо. Разбирайтесь с вашими данными. Может быть вы не те аргументы взяли для `curve_fit`, может быть ещё что-то. Первым делом вам нужно разобраться что у вас `X`, что у вас `Y` и какую собственно задачу вы вообще решаете. Я из вашего вопроса этого не смог до конца понять.

Comment: Вы правы на 100%, и я действительно не совсем правильно изложил свою проблему. Функция Басса, это функция распространения инноваций, способная предсказывать распространение нового продукта на рынке, определив параметры P, Q и M. У меня это реализовано в excel по следующей схеме: помимо строк year и generate есть ещё строки bass и pred_generate(предсказанная генерация), сначала заполняется ячейка pred_generate(первый элемент берется от generate), далее эти данные передаются в функцию bass и заполняется 2 ячейка строки bass (в первой 0), далее вторая ячейка pred_generate(pred_generate[-1]+bass)

Comment: Далее 2 ячейка pred_generate передается в формулу bass и заполняется 3 ячейка строки bass и так далее. При этом параметры P, Q и M должны быть такими, что бы сумма разности квадратов pred_generate и generate была минимальной. Обучившись на существующих данных, можно и предсказать что будет. Изначально я подумал, что определив P, Q и M я смогу предсказать, но как мне кажется, я передавал не те данные. Вроде бы теперь изложил все что хочу сделать, надеюсь понятно.

Comment: С трудом понимаю. Попробую завтра ещё подумать )

Comment: Если не будет понятно, вот ссылка на файл https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Brf9i2UuIsDNZrpCw5M-ssYsClMwMQ9v/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107290803044622327748&rtpof=true&sd=true, там формулами показано как заполняются ячейки. Очень Вам благодарен, надеюсь Вы мне поможете.

Comment: curve_fit мне даёт только подгонку кривой под данные. А что бы продолжить эту кривую, мне необходимо эти данные предсказать, а как мне это сделать самым простым способом (или не простым) не знаю.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в последние дни вообще времени нет ни на что (  Как только появится - попытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Получается у меня есть данные, формула по которой эти данные распространяются. А вот как предугадать какие будут дальше данные? Я понимаю что данные надо основные и тренировочные, натренировать модель, а потом эту модель применить ко всем данным, и получить новые сгенерированные данные. Как мне это лучше и проще сделать?